# Landsat8 View Imagery Service in ArcMap Layer Time Issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, time

I'm attempting to work with one of the newer ArcGIS Online subscription imagery services called Landsat 8 Views which allows you to view Landsat data for the US across several dates in 2013.  I can get the imagery service to click thru the various dates in arcgis.com viewer but not in ArcMap 10.2  When I attempt to enable time on the Landsat 8 Views layer in ArcMap it removes the layer from even being visible.  Any ideas what may be going on here and what may be wrong?  It's a huge amount of data in the attribute table and possibly part of the problem.  I would like to clip specific dates for small areas but I can only get a single date to show which I guess is the one displaying on top.

The server address for the Landsat 8 Views is **[here](http://landsat.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Landsat8_Views/ImageServer)**.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out my problem if anyone was interested.  Basically, the Time tab under Layer Properties needs to be in the same units as the Time slider or it won't display.  Secondly, if the time intervals are too small it takes very long to click thru them.  It would be nice if the time interval would automatically click thru only the dates available vs. this arbitrary time interval but it doesn't seem to do that.  Since it doesn't I predict most will be confused by the time feature and using the time slider.